# ArcGIS Online scrape info from a website dynamically

Tags: arcgis-online, arcade

It seems like this is do-able but I don't know what tools would work best. I have a feature service of Parcel data that includes a parcel PIN. Each parcel has a corresponding web page that can be accessed by appending the PIN to a static url. Once you're on that page there is a plethora of additional information in tables. I would like to be able to extract this info and append it to my feature service.

For example, I would like each parcel to include the Owner name in the Pop-up. Owner name is listed on the webpage, so I should be able to scrape it somehow. Ideally a solution would do this using Arcade in the Pop-up so it's always correct, but I would be fine with running a tool ever so often.

Is there a way to do this in ArcGIS Online, or with some other open source tool that is more simple than, "build a web scraper?"

Comment: sounds like this breaks some privacy laws having owners name available on the internet (especially under EU law)

Comment: @mapperz This type of information is commonly available for real estate in the US. It's often provided by the county auditor, which is an official local government office, so it's presumably not illegal here.

Comment: Yes, this is definitely public information in the US, or at least in every state I've done work in. In this case, it's Pennsylvania.